# Python on Emacs taking space on disk

Tags: python, elpy, environment

I'm kind of a newbie and want to use Python on Emacs.

I noticed that there is a folder rpc-venv here:

```
/Users/user/.emacs/elpy/rpc-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Where all python packages are installed.

Why are these files copied here?
Why is Emacs not using the already installed files from the system?

Thanks!

Comment: smells like a python virtual environment

Comment: SO I could delete it? How is the approach to delete the env from Emacs?

Comment: no, don't. it's required for `elpy`.

Comment: What I could do is delete the heavy weight, and reinstall elpy with everything whenever I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where all python packages are installed.

No. These are just the Python packages that elpy needs.

This is a Python [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) (called “venv” for short). It contains the specific versions of packages needed by one application. Using a venv avoids mixing potentially incompatible versions of packages (the Python ecosystem is huge, and on the whole not great at maintaining backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an `elpy` user, so someone else might be able to provide more.

Googling for "elpy" and ".emacs/elpy/rpc-venv", brings us right to the `elpy` documentation, specifically https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html

Quoting the third paragraph of [The RPC Process](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#the-rpc-process) on that page:

> RPC processes are used to provide code completion, documentation and other features. To do so, they use python packages (jedi, yapf, …) that are installed in a dedicated virtualenv (**.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv** by default). Those packages can be updated through the configuration panel (accessible with M-x elpy-config).

So `~/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-env` is a python virtualenv that is required for `elpy` to do the things it does. Don't delete it, let `elpy` manage it. If you don't like where it is, it sounds like you can configure its location.